# Ignore a directory when pull/push in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I've got a situation where I have a dev and QA version of a repo.

I have a directory foo, which contains code that I always want to be pushed/pulled.
I have a directory bar, which typically contains items specific to that region (what they are is irrelevant), but sometimes will contain items that I do want to push/pull.

- push to qa - in such a way that it will only take foo, but ignore the changes in bar.
- push to qa - in such a way that it will take both foo and bar.
- push to qa - in such a way that it will take foo and some of bar.

From what I can tell, I would need to merge, then revert certain files back and then commit these. This is OK, but seems a bit backwards. Is there a better way to get Mercurial to support this workflow (Or a similar one)?

Comment: Pushing works at the changeset level. If the changeset includes things you don't want, you'll need to resolve that yourself in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris Morgan says, that's not really the way that Mercurial works.  When you push to another repository, you push a number of changesets - anything that's in those changesets gets pushed.

One possible solution, although it's a *very horrid* workaround (in my opinion) would be to use the [Convert](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) extension to create a new repository, filtering out what you don't want by using the `--filemap` option.

However, if this is going to QA, would they need a Mercurial repository anyway?  You could simply archive a (tagged) version.  By default the archive will contain information on the changeset that you're archiving in the `.hgarchival` file.  For example

```
hg archive -X "bar/**" archive.tgz
```

... will create a file `archive.tgz` containing an archive of your repo at the current point, without the "bar" directory.  The `-X` option can be used multiple times if you wish to exclude specific files.